# Is there a way for get the inner value of this Lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net

I have an "ID" inside of lambda expression, but Im not sure how to to get the value to send it to a main controller.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
```

I have the ID inside of that lambda expression, I tried getting the id directly from the model "model.id".

I tried creating a new variable like this:

```
var id1 =@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
```

But I get this error :

A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).

**Code**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

@Html.ActionLink("Approve", "ControllerAprove", new {id = model.id}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-large" })
```

1 - If I try to use 
`new {id = model.id}` the value of id its equal to 0.

2 - If I try:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

@{var ID1 = @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id);}

@Html.ActionLink("Approve", "ControllerAprove", new {id =ID1}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-large" })
```

Then I get A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).

Comment: and what if you remove @ from helper? It stored into variable?

Comment: also hiddenFor is Form element you will need send by form then. Also your code works as expected id = model.id. Try check data type. If you have int and ID is null then send as 0. You need change to nullable like int? then send null.